# How stack exchange puts up a question in "Hot Network Questions" list?

Tags: support, hot-questions

I referred [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222991/ease-up-on-the-hot-network-question-randomness) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254237/astroturfing-in-hot-network-questions) and searched even more but I did not get a clear answer. So I decided to ask it here.

**Questions**

1. What is the criteria of a question to be put up in "Hot network questions" list?
2. How a particular question is picked up and ranked and that too among different stack communities? How question ranking algorithm works. Clearly, only upvotes does not matter.
3. Can it ever happen that one particular community possess all or more positions in the list? For ex, Currently, I observe only two or maximum three **hot** questions of a particular community in the list. Suppose, a community B got 10 great questions, is there any possibility that the list will show up more than 4 or 5 questions of community B?

Comment: The formula is explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/295232). I think it even explains 3., so your question can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @PatrickHofman there's no cap, but subsequent questions from the same community get a score reduction. This is also explained in the answer.